# Unsupported Device on Google Play

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-services

I have made app which is not supported on 1436 Devices on Google Play Store

i have used Google MapV2

Google play Store : No eligible devices for app install

List of Devices :

- Nexus 7 (2012)– tilapia
- Nexus 7 (2012)– grouper
- Lenovo N308-SmartAIO
- Lenovo A396– A396_TY
- Lenovo P700– p700
- S61– ideatv_S61
- Lenovo A399– Aiken
- LIFETAB E10316– LIFETAB_E10316
- olleh– ik1
- Behold II– sgh-t939
- Spica– spica
- GT-I5800L–
- GT-I5800L
- Galaxy Ace3– logan3gcmcc
- Galaxy– gt-i7500
- Galaxy Player 50– YP-G50
- Galaxy Spica– GT-I5700L
- Galaxy Tab3 Kids– lt02kidswifi
- Europa– GT-I5500M
- Behold II– SGH_T939
- Galaxy Star Plus– logan2g
- Galaxy S4– jfwifi
- Homesync– spcwifiMoment– SPH-M900
- Samsung Homesync– spcwifiany
- Galaxy Star2 Plus– higgs2g
- Galaxy Tab 10.1– GT-P7503
- Galaxy 070– hendrix
- Galaxy Young2– young2ds2g
- Gear Live– sprat
- Moment– sph-m900
- Galaxy Star– mint
- Galaxy Star– mintss
- Galaxy S5– kwifi
- Lenovo N308– SmartAIO
- Lenovo A396– A396_TY
- Lenovo P700– p700
- S61– ideatv_S61
- Lenovo A399– Aiken
- LIFETAB E10316– LIFETAB_E10316

And many more...

Please Help me.

```
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <permission android:name="com.xxxxx.xxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permissionandroid:name com.xxxxx.xxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE="" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/tracker" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: what is your android:minSdkVersion?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion ="8"

Comment: what is google_play_services_version?

Answer (score 1):

Some permissions imply feature requirements. For example camera by default requires android.hardware.camera and android.hardware.camera.autofocus. This makes phones with fixed focus cameras incompatible.

To know more check this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions